# Find the maximum attainable value of $2c+2a-b$.

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$a^2+b^2+c^2=2018$$ $$2a+2b-c=15$$ $$2b+2c-a=36$$ Find the maximum attainable value of $2c+2a-b$.

I don't really know how to do. I can't handle all the provided conditions.

Comment: Use $c=7+a$, $b=11-a/2$ and $a^2 + (11-a/2)^2+(7-a)^2=2018$ to compute two values of $a$. Pick the one that maximizes $2c+2a-b=3+9a/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Solve the two linear constraints for two of the variables, and plug in to the quadratic constraint.  You can then solve that: there should be just two points.  Pick the one with the biggest value of the objective.

Answer (score 1):

from the second and third equation we get
$$2a+2b-15=c$$ so we get
$$-a+2b+2(2a+2b-15)=36$$
or
$$a+2b=22$$
and $$a^2+b^2+(2a+2b-15)^2=2018$$
Can you finish?
with $$a=22-2b$$ we obtain
$$(22-2b)^2+b^2+(2(22-2b)+2b-15)^2-2018=0$$ a equation in $b$
simplifying this and factorizing we get finally
$$3\, \left( b+3 \right)  \left( 3\,b-77 \right) =0$$

Comment: i will check this!

Comment: i have found no error

Comment: i have forgotten to write the $b$, but it stands on my sheet of paper

Comment: yes ok but it was not missed on my sheet of paper, the calculations are right, and thank you for the hint

Comment: what do you mean?